# How to display multiple member variables for multiple member ids on same page?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am trying to display values from the same set of variables for different members within the same mysql database, using PHP within one public web page. For instance, one web page will show the following data for different members, each having different IDs:

```
id //unique identifier
city
state
price
description
```

I am able to display these values for one member's data by simply using the GET variables in the URL. But I need to display data from these variables for multiple members, each having a different ID.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually simpler, unless I am missing something. You need to query using something like this:

```
SELECT id, city, state, price, description FROM Members
```

We would need more information about your database to be more helpful. For example, I seriously doubt that "price" is a valid field for a "member" table.

Comment: You forgot to add a conditional statement selecting just the members he wants to display on the page (signaled through a $_GET).

Comment: What would the code used in the html look like to pull up data for each unique ID? The variables are used multiple times within the same page and must be associated with a specific member ID. The page needs to know which member they are pulling values from for each set of variables (all of which are the same).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, city, state, price, description FROM users WHERE id IN ({ids})
```

Just replace {ids} with a comma separated array of ids of the users. I don't know how exactly you are getting the ids through a $_GET, but if it's through an array, simply do an `implode(",", $_GET["ids"])`.

Comment: I got the first part of your answer, but not sure of the second. There are new members with new IDs coming into the database daily. So I can't list all the IDs.

Comment: My question was **how** do you know what IDs to select? You didn't give an example at all how you receive those ids, so I cannot give you an example on how to code it in PHP.

Comment: Well, because my use scenario is going to change in the future, I'm going to manually insert IDs into the html. Based on the ID, the values for the above variables should appear under each user listing on the page